# Shared Caching in Java Across Multiple Applications

Tags: java, spring, caching

I am using Spring caching with CacheManager and Cacheable to cache the same data from the same table in 10 different applications. The assumption upon implementation was that this data we are caching is meta data and should not be changed. However, they are changing this data and the cache is never being cleared.

Now the requirement is to clear the cache for all 10 applications at the same time with 2 big asks.

1. Whenever the table changes from direct INSERT statements on mySQL Work Bench 
   all the applications cache should be refreshed. I am using Hibernate and 
   Spring, but remember that the inserts are happening outside of the 
   applications that are caching the data.
2. If I expose an API to refresh the cache it should be 1 API that will refresh 
   all 10 applications. Currently the caches are private and not exposed outside of the application.

Is there some caching mechanism that I can implement so that all 10 of these applications will use the same underlying cache. Therefore, if I refresh 1 then all applications will get updated data.

I currently believe, and found from research, that putting a Trigger in the database to execute the Java code is a bad idea. Are these asks impossible to implement?

CacheManager: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html

Answer (score 0):

If those 10 applications are instances of the same app, I guess you could define a new `@RequestMapping("/clear-cache")` and call all of them when there is a change. But if they are different applications then this would be a mess, unless the code is shared.

I am assuming the freshness of the data is not critical since you mentioned the cache contains metadata. So another option would be to refresh all the caches periodically with scheduled method.

Another option would be to centralize this cache somehow in another process (redis, etc) so all your applications get their data from the same cache.